# Identify whether PCB 1/4" audio jacks are balanced or unbalanced

Tags: pcb, audio, analog, pcb-layers

I have a Fostex 2016 line mixer and was trying to see in the manual (https://www.fostexinternational.com/docs/tech_support/manuals.shtml) whether the 1/4" inputs and outputs are balanced (TRS) or unbalanced (TS).

Finding no information in the manual, I took the unit apart to look at the PCB. See the two images below:

I see the sleeve soldered to the ground plane (is that the right term?) which makes sense.  Then I see the tip soldered to pads that are clearly connecting to audio lines, which also makes sense.  I believe the soldered pad in between the two is for the ring, which in this case seems isolated (meaning it is an unbalanced connector).  It seems like a super-basic PCB so I am guessing that there are no interior layers but just wanted to confirm.  I am also confused why there are five lines going to the 4 line-out connectors (the two other connectors are for aux sends, I believe, and the single black pin is GND.

[image: PCB top]

[image: PCB bottom]

I appreciate any help clarifying the answer to this question and maybe even educating me on some analog audio electronics at the same time ;).

Comment: I'm 99.9% sure these were unbalanced - also strongly suggested by the -10dBV operating level. To be sure, you could verify that middle solder pad doesn't actually go anywhere.

Comment: Given it's a single sided print...it 99.9% doesn't go anywhere. xD Even if the jack itself is TRS compatible, the circuitry certainly isn't.

Comment: @TylerStone thanks. Why does the -10dbV suggest unbalanced?

Comment: @NatsuKage thanks. I will put the meter on it to double-check!

Comment: @Zachary Russell Heineman de facto standard for consumer audio gear...most balanced I/O would operate at +4, with some devices (DBX compressors come to mind) having balanced I/O but with the operating level switchable between -10 and +4.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the block diagram, the input jacks are unbalanced, with the third terminal being a switch contact to the tip.  The switch contacts connect to RCA jacks on the rear panel, which will be disconnected when a plug is inserted in the front jack.

[image]

The tip contact is the "V" at the end of the top line of the jack, and the switch contact is the upward-pointing arrow under the line.

Comment: The photos I posted were of the line outs and aux rtn 1-2, so a different part of the unit, but I appreciate your taking a look at it.  I am interested where in the block diagram I would see the switching you mention.  Is there a way you could post an image of that area with some annotation?  My apologies I don't have a lot of experience with reading these types of things.